# How to validate in each step the required fields? (that is, the next button should only work if required fields are valid and not empty)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I´m creating a multi-step form using bootstrap and jquery with 4 steps.

But I want that in each step validate the required fields, that is, the button to go to the next step should only work if the required fields are not empty.

But I´m not having success implementing this part of validating each step the required fields. Do you know how to do that?

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/4vzf9qgr/2/

Jquery:

```
$(function(){

  // navigation buttons

  $('a.nav-link').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if ($target.parent().hasClass('disabled')) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });

  $(".next-step").click(function (e) {
    var $active = $('.nav-pills li a.active');
    $active.parent().next().removeClass('disabled');
    nextTab($active);
  });

  $(".prev-step").click(function (e) {
    var $active = $('.nav-pills li a.active');
    prevTab($active);
  });

  function nextTab(elem) {
    $(elem).parent().next().find('a.nav-link').click();
  }
  function prevTab(elem) {
    $(elem).parent().prev().find('a.nav-link').click();
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="bg-light-gray2">
  <div class="container nopadding py-4">
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h1 class="h5 text-center text-heading-blue font-weight-bold">Page Title</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mt-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="registration_form">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills bg-light-gray registration_form_list" role="tablist">
            <li class="">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
                Step 1<br><small class="d-none d-md-inline-block">General Info</small></a>
            </li>
            <li class="disabled">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
                Step 2<br><small class="d-none d-md-inline-block">Conference Creator Info</small></a>
            </li>
            <li class="disabled">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
                Step 3<br><small class="d-none d-md-inline-block">Registration Types</small></a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <form method="post" name="test" class="clearfix" action="/conference/store">
            <div class="tab-content registration_body bg-white" id="myTabContent">
              <div class="tab-pane fade show active clearfix" id="step1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="conference_name" class="text-heading h6 font-weight-semi-bold">Conference Name</label>
                  <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="conference_name" id="conference_name">
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                    <label for="conference_categories" class="text-heading h6 font-weight-semi-bold">Categories</label>
                    <select id="tag_list"  multiple class="form-control" name="conference_categories" id="conference_categories">
                      <option>category1</option>
                      <option>category2</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>



                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="textarea" class="text-heading h6 font-weight-semi-bold">Description</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" name="conference_description" id="textarea" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="float-right">
                  <button type="button" href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"
                          class="btn mr-2 btn-primary btn next-step">
                    Go To Step 2
                  </button>
                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="tab-pane fade clearfix" id="step2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">


                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="conference_organizer_description" class="text-heading h6 font-weight-semi-bold">Description</label>
                  <textarea name="organizer_description" id="conference_organizer_description" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>

                <button type="button" href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"
                        class="btn mr-2 btn-outline-primary btn prev-step">
                  Back to Step 1
                </button>
                <button type="button" href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"
                        class="btn mr-2 btn-primary btn next-step">
                  Go To Step 3
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane clearfix fade" id="step3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="registration_type_name" class="text-heading h6 font-weight-semi-bold">Registration Type Name</label>
                  <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="registration_type_name" id="registration_type_name">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="registration_type_description" class="text-heading h6 font-weight-semi-bold">Registration Type Description</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="registration_type_description" id="registration_type_description">
                </div>

                <button type="button" href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"
                        class="btn mr-2 btn-outline-primary btn prev-step">
                  Go Back To Step 2
                </button>
                <button type="submit"
                        class="btn mr-2 btn-primary btn">
                  Store
                </button>

              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to use the div IDs that you have ("#step1", "#step2", etc) and have the button be disabled unless the following function returns true:

```
function validateForm(divId)
    {
        var inputs, index;
        var form=document.getElementById(formId);
        inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
            // deal with inputs[index] element.
            if (inputs[index].value==null || inputs[index].value=="")
            {
                alert("Field is empty");
                $(buttonID).prop('disabled', true);
                return
            }
        }
        $(buttonID).prop('disabled', false);
    }
```

**Update/Additional comments:**

I changed the function above to set the button instead of returning anything. At form load, have the button be disabled. Then add an onfocus attr to run an event listener like this:

```
function validateFormListener(divID, formObject) {
    formObject.addEventListener("input", function(evt) {
      validateForm(divID, buttonID)
    })
}
```

Give the button an ID, then replace buttonID in the examples with this name. Change the input tags to look like this:

```
<input type="text" required class="form-control" onfocus="validateFormListener('#step1', buttonID, this)" name="conference_name" id="conference_name">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how to use that function in the question example? Because it is only one form for 3 steps.